# How to run only some commands in a Windows batch file as admin?

Tags: batch-file, admin, windows-firewall, elevated-privileges, video-conferencing

Via email, I'm helping someone else set up Windows 7 firewall rules to prevent the Zoom video conferencing client from possibly accessing the internet unless it is explicitly launched by the user.  *(No current evidence that Zoom does this, but with all the issues revealed about Zoom, she wants to be extra cautious.)*

She has the "allow" Windows Firewall rules set up and named them "Zoom 1" & "Zoom 2" (the "1" and "2" are for OUT and IN rules).

So now, when she want wants to use Zoom, she enables those 2 firewall rules, and when she's done, she disables them.

I want to help her automate this, so I wrote a simple batch file and sent it to her:

```
 netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Zoom 1" new enable=yes
 netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Zoom 2" new enable=yes
 pathname\zoom.exe
 netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Zoom 1" new enable=no
 netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Zoom 2" new enable=no
```

When she runs it, she gets notified that "The requested operation requires elevation" (admin) for the `netsh` commands.

How can this batch file be modified to run the `netsh` commands as admin, but not `zoom.exe`?

Comment: does `runas /trustlevel:0x10000 zoom.exe` work?

Comment: @HackingAddict1337 If it successfully runs zoom.exe, how would she determine the trust level at which it is actually running?

Comment: use external tools like [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

Comment: or, `explorer zoom.exe` also works

Comment: @HackingAddict1337 Thank you for the tips.  What technique do you recommend for running the batch file with elevation so that the `netsh` commands work?

Comment: i'm not sure if i'm getting it. do you mean auto-elevation?

Comment: @HackingAddict1337 Currently, she get the message "the requested operation requires elevation" for the `netsh` commands.  A way to solve that issue.

Comment: Try https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean, but:

```
@echo off
net session >nul 2>&1 || (
MSHTA "javascript: var shell = new ActiveXObject('shell.application'); shell.ShellExecute('%~nx0', '', '', 'runas', 1);close();"
exit /b
)
whoami /priv
pause
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Zoom 1" new enable=yes
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Zoom 2" new enable=yes
explorer zoom.exe
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Zoom 1" new enable=no
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Zoom 2" new enable=no
```

Use `mshta` to prompt UAC.

`explorer` ALWAYS runs at medium (or low) integrity, no matter the parent process' integrity level.